# Question with LC3 Assembly Outputting to console

Tags: assembly, output, divide, lc3

I have a multi digit number in register R4, I need to print that number to the terminal "ex. 23".

I can't figure out the dividing algorithm to isolate the 2 and the 3 to convert to ASCII.

The final output should be something like "Your answer is: 23"

What if the answer is less than 10? How do I check? Also the answer shouldn't exceed 100 typically.

Any help?

Comment: You divide by 10, getting quotient and remainder.

Comment: e.g. the algorithm (in C) looks like [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894)